# How to map Int to int8 by default?

Tags: hibernate, mapping

I have an existing model implementation that needs to work with a new database.

Can i configure Hibernate to map int variables to int8 instead of int4 by default?

Comment: An int in Java has 4 bytes. Why would you want to map it to int8?

Comment: because the database doesn't have int4. it has absolute no 4 byte types.

Comment: Which database is it? And which dialect are you using? I find it surprising that Hibernate tries to map to an unexisting type, unless you're not using the appropriate dialect for your database.

Comment: the database is vertica (from HP) following the supports advice i'm using the postgres dialect (that works pretty well) unfortunately my existing model uses int but vertica doesn't have any 4 bit types.

Comment: I think that you're going to write a dialect for this database, or generate the schema by hand.

Comment: i took a look at the postgres dialect code and i think your right. type mapping is registered using registerColumnType(...). So i think i will create a new dialect that inherits postgres.

Comment: I have Postgres 8 and an int8 type and I use long, it works OK for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a new Dialect for my specific Database type as proposed in a comment.